# not able to screenshot full webpage in SharePoint 2013 using Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, screenshot, sharepoint-2013

Does anyone know why I would not be able to do a full screenshot of a SharePoint 2013 webpage using firefox?

I have tried Nimbus and Awesome screenshots plugins as well as the command line option: `screenshot --fullpage`. All it captures is the visible part. Works fine for all other websites, even SharePoint 2010.

Comment: What if you use [Ctrl] + [-] to zoom out?

Comment: I am able to capture the whole page but the text is really small. good work around -thanks

Comment: Another workaround that could work would be to print the page as a pdf. You could also try doing that in chrome to see if it's better/worse.

Comment: Printing in Firefox didn't work. Printing in IE8 brought some results, but still far from perfect.

Answer (score 1):

FireShot is only capture app that knows how to scroll sharepoint layout and take screenshot.

Problem is in sharepoint masterpage: body element is fixed and content is in  `<div id="s4-workspace">` with overflow:auto

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to the original question, but I found a way to take a nice screenshot of a Sharepoint website. My solution that worked was IE8 + [FireShot](http://getfireshot.com/). Interestingly enough, the same plugin didn't work correctly for SharePoint in Firefox 35.